# How do I set up a link to open up Visual Studio Code from terminal on OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, visual-studio-code

I've recently installed [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and I love it!  In the past, I've used sublime text 2/3 and at some point I copied code to allow `subl .` command to open the current directory with sublime.

**Question:**

- How can I write a similar code to allow visual studio code to open up the current directory like I've done in the past with sublime.
- Where should I put paste this code?

Desired alias/link/command would be `code .`

[Does the command on this video](https://youtu.be/HmWm21cCAXM?t=208)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From version 1.0 use the command `Install 'Code' command in path` from the command palette (`View | Command Palette`) to make Code available to the command line.

**Historical answer:**

With VSCode 0.3.0 the startup script should now be configured to be this:

```
code () {
    VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If this doesnt work for you uninstall VSC and reinstall it; for this will only work with 0.3.0+

Comment: Yes, this one ensures that VSCode picks the correct current working directory and also ensures you can add multiple arguments (e.g. to open multiple folders or files at the same time).

Answer (score 9):

> Visual Code has a self-service means to do the same!

Followed https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_installation

[image: Enable <code>code</code> to open visual-code on mac]

Comment: Easy peasy. Mac users just press cmd+shift+p and type 'shell' to get above screenshot results

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

As pointed out in comments by Tony, `Atom Shell` has been renamed to `Electron`.
My updated code should read:

```
code() { (/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron "$1" &) }
```

Also, I recommend using [official way](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/setup), as described in [Benjamin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30627956/4699494):

```
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*; }
```

---

You should create a command to start the editor in `~/.bash_profile` file. This file is read each time you open terminal and start your bash session.

As the process should be started in the background and we want to pass a directory or a file as an argument I would add such single line function to `.bash profile`:

```
code() { (/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom "$1" &) }
```

Where `/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app` is a path to your Visual Studio Code app. You may need to adjust it if you installed it somewhere else.

This function opens Atom editor that is a base of Visual Studio Code and passes the first parameter to it with `$1` expansion. Ampersand `&` will make the process detach from terminal and run in the background. The whole function body is put in brackets `()` to quiet messages about detaching and ending the process.

If the `.bash_profile` file is missing on your system you will have to create it first.

After editing the file you will have to restart your current bash session.

Comment: Very great write up man! I hope you get tons of upvotes soon!

Comment: Latest version change Atom to Electron

Answer (score 3):

I set it up following the docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup and added a `code` definition to my `.bash_profile`.

UPDATE (6/10/2015): This answer originally contained the code from the linked site. I have now removed the code from this answer as the linked site now recommends a different `code` implementation. (as Benjamin pointed out in the comments). Please see the link for the recommended code to add to your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: This is not the recommended syntax anymore!

Comment: Cool, thanks @BenjaminPasero. I removed the old code from my answer.